# Estou tendo um erro com um bot para fazer operações no IQ Option

Tags: python, índices

Ele consegue as vezes fazer as entradas, mas sempre no final da esse erro, e não sei como resolver

```
Erro:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 267, in <module>
    par = x.split(';')[1].upper()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

site do criador da api: https://github.com/viniciuscbb/bot-sinais

Comment: A mensagem de erro é clara, poderia colocar na pergunta o fragmento de código que gera esse erro, para que possamos lhe oferecer uma resposta precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Você está recebendo este erro por estar tentando acessar um índice em um array que não existe.

Uma maneira de tentar resolver é verificando o tamanho do array depois de fazer o split pelo valor <kbd>;</kbd>

```
arrpar = x.split(';')
par = ""
if len(arrpar) >= 2:
    par = arrpar[1].upper()
```

Estou verificando se o valor é `>=` a dois, pois o primeiro índice do array é o valor zero (python utiliza arrays indexados com índice zero). Como queremos o valor de índice 1 devemos verificar se o vetor (array) possui o tamanho maior ou igual à 2.

Verifique também que agora o valor da sua variável `par` será "" (string vazia), para o caso de não haver um array com mais de 2 posições.